# Pentesting a website for SQL Injection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, sql-injection

I have created a website using `ASP.NET` and `SQL Server`. Now I am testing the web site for vulnerabilities. As I tested the web against various inputs, it refused the invalid inputs. Some inputs however, like : `admin' or 1=1--` when entered the web site keeps loading forever and then it timeouts. Does this indicate a `SQL Injection` vulnerability?

P.S: I did my homework on using parametrized queries rather than concatenating strings, I am also aware of various tools used to automate `SQL Injection` like `SQL Map`.

Comment: to answer that question you should first establish where that endless loop happens

Answer (score 1):

1=1-- could cause to select all users in database, if you have so large amount of users, it might cause the hanging. Otherwise something else is going on.

Overally I think you should check your website for SQL injections using automated SQL injection tools like Sqlmap. It's open-source and coded in Python. Also you can scan your entire website for all type of security vulnerabilities using Acunetix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it's a website that you have created, you should be aware of the SQL statement for the login.

For instance, if the SQL statement looks like below.

```
SELECT username, passwd  FROM table_name WHERE username='<userinput>' AND passwd='<userinput>';
```

Here  is what you provide in your login form. Now with the above as the query, think of various ways in which you can make the above statement true.

For ex:

Assuming that comments are not escaped.

> 'validusername' AND '1'='1'-- //
>
> ' OR '1'='1'-- //

If comment character is escaped or doesn't work:

> ' OR '1'='1

These are some basic attack vectors for SQLi on login page. You can refer to the cheatsheet on the this [link](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet) for more.

Since you are a developer reviewing the code is a better way for you to understand if SQLi is possible. I just wanted to give you an insight of a pentester.